# UTF-8 in Marketing Cloud SQL Queries

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, encoding

Are there any chances to define in what encoding the query result will be?
Let's say I have a standard query:

```
select field1, field2, field3
from DataExtension
```

How should the query look like if the field1 needs to be in UTF-8? Or, if possible, all the fields.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your use case for this?

Comment: @zuzannamj, we keep Cyrillic symbols in the fields and when we query them in Query Studio, we get question marks instead. There is a workaround. We can create a DE and then populate it with the pre-saved query via Automation studio, but it's inconvenient and time-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

No, there aren't - SQL activities in Marketing Cloud are based on SQL Server 2016 capabilities and SQL Server 2016 doesn't support UTF-8.